# Redis-py connection doesn't timeout

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I have a very simple implementation on python using redis-py to interface with Redis.
As part of the development, I am shutting redis down to simulate a timeout exception.
Problem is that I am setting the timeout to a few seconds, but the connection just sits there without timing out.

```
from redis import StrictRedis
print('Connecting')
redis_instance = StrictRedis(host=settings.REDIS_HOST,
                             port=settings.REDIS_PORT, 
                             db=settings.REDIS_DB,
                             socket_connect_timeout=5,
                             socket_timeout=5,
                                  )
print('Setting key')
redis_instance.set('X','Y')
print('Key SET')
```

I can see it goes up to `Setting key` message, but doesnt go beyond that or throw a timeout.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @dizzyf before starting anything….

Answer (score -1):

If you shutdown redis before running the code. redis-py raises socket exception `ConnectionRefusedError`, and redis `ConnectionError`.

You have not connected the redis yet, how could the connection times out?

Comment: Thats the issue. It doesn’t raise any error, regardless of being or not a timeout.